# asp.net can't change current culture

Tags: asp.net, multilingual

I am using asp.net localization to try and create a multi-langauge website, basically i have two global resources one for english and another for arabic.

i added a dropdown list containig the two languages:

```
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="changeLang" AutoPostBack="true" >
      <asp:ListItem Value="en">English</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="ar">Arabic</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

and i am using this code-behind:

```
 protected override void InitializeCulture() //changing the languages
    {
        string lang = Request["changeLang"];

        if (lang != null && lang != "")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
        }
    }
```

but the language wont change and **on debugging the value of the string lang is always null.**

i am using asp.net 4.0.

what is the problem, thanks.

Comment: I'm missing `MyBase.InitializeCulture()` at the end. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter - i tried adding it at the end of the code but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there are two separate issues.

1) You aren't getting the value from the dropdown list in your code-behind just null. Have you tried directly accessing the object rather than going thru the Request object. For example: 
 `string lang = changeLang.SelectedValue`

2) The cultures are not being set. For the second item try creating the specific culture first and using it for both the `CurrentUICulture` and `CurrentCulture`. For example:

```
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
```

Additionally it looks like you might be following the code sample from this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You need to use specific culture identifiers in your dropdown (eg en-US and ar-EG)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest setting the page to automatically determine the culture from the user's browser settings:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="auto" Culture="auto" %>
```

Or same the whole site, by adding these entries to your `web.config` file:

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" /><!-- Automatically set culture from HTTP request -->
<globalization uiCulture="auto:en" culture="auto:en-US" /><!-- Optionally set a default culture -->
```

Then use *Implicit Declarative Binding* on your controls:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
    meta:resourcekey="btnSubmit" />
```

See [Resources and Localization in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx) for plenty of details and code samples.  If you'd rather do it programmatically as per your example, see the following resources:

- [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx)

Comment: Auto culture setting works fine, my problem is i need to change the culture manually.

Comment: Didn't answer the users question